# What is the best practice to split up a long global.css in an Omega theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I am building out a theme based on the excellent base theme Omega. I am using the standard CSS files for narrow, normal, etc. My global.css file is getting large. I would like to split it up. Is there any kind of best practice for this in Omega, or should I just do as I would any other Drupal theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you subthemed Omega? I would say just modify your .info file and include an extra css file. I do it all the time, splitting them on function, i.e. styling for node templates etc. in one file and so on.

Comment: Yes, I did sub-theme. Thanks! Just wanted to sanity check.